# PFE with complex roots on TI-89

Tags: partial-fractions, calculator

How to do partial fraction expansion with complex roots on a TI-89 (i.e. from formula #1 to its expansion form #2)? With real roots, I could use the `Algebra/expand()` function but it just returns the formula itself if there's a complex root.

1. $ Z(p) = {16p \over p^2 + 4} $
2. $ Z(p) = { 8 \over p + 2i } + { 8 \over p-2i} $

Comment: Use a CAS online instead of the T-1000.

Comment: @DietrichBurde any link? I searched around online but couldn't find anything that solve for complex roots. The closest thing I found was [WolframAlpha Widgets](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=ec4a062bb304f88c2ba0b631d7acabbc) but it again only solves for real roots.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3083639/how-to-do-partial-fraction-decomposition-with-complex-roots). You can also do it by hand, like there.

Comment: I'm looking for a tool to compute that instead of by hand hence the question.

Comment: See for partial fractions [here](https://agraef.github.io/pure-docs/pure-reduce.html). This should work also for complex numbers. You should perhaps give a less trivial example in the post, so that one can understand the motivation to use a CAS.

Comment: Thanks, though getting it up and running looks more complicated than solving it by hand. I guess I'll just pay for Mathematica or something...